Getting nearly 100% accuracy using Binary Classification in Tensorflow but incredibly wrong prediction levels for email messages
I'm creating a Chrome Extension to read user emails via Gmail's API, and then passing in user emails to a trained Keras model in Flask to determine whether the email was written by an AI or a Human, with a dataset of 700 emails for both, 1400 in total. My accuracy ratings display no less than 92% accuracy for 10 epochs, however, when passing in emails I used verbatim from the data set such as a human-written email, I'm getting 99% prediction ratings that the email was written by AI, and vice-versa. I'm new to NLP and ML, so I was wondering if the way Im handling classification is the problem.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import glob
import html
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, SpatialDropout1D, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


app = Flask(__name__)

def train_aiVShuman_email():
    max_files = 700
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    folder_path_ai = os.path.join(root_dir, 'Data/AI_Phising Email Dataset Filtered')
    folder_path_human = os.path.join(root_dir, 'Data/Enron DataSet Filtering')
 
    AI_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path_ai, '*.txt'))[:max_files]
    Test_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path_human, '*.txt'))[:max_files]

    texts = []
    labels = []

    for file in AI_files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            texts.append(f.read())
        labels.append(1)  # Positive class

    for file in Test_files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            texts.append(f.read())
        labels.append(0)  # Negative class

    max_words = 1000  # Max words to tokenize
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)

    X = np.array(padded_sequences)
    y = np.array(labels)

    embedding_dim = 100
    max_len = X.shape[1]  # Max length of sequences based on padded sequences

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=max_words, output_dim=embedding_dim))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35, random_state=42)

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2)

    # Save model
    model.save('Keras Models/aiVShuman.keras')
    print("aiVShuman model saved Successfully")
    return model  



#Train model using train_aiVShuman_email function, which saves it to keras. Takes about 10 min so dont run everytime
#model = train_aiVShuman_email()

#Takes saved model, and uses it for prediction
model = load_model('Keras Models/aiVShuman.keras')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #train_aiVShuman_email()

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000) 
    data = request.json
    message = data['message']
    #print(message)

    #Gets rid of HTML digits and converts them back to characters
    message = html.unescape(message)
    message = [message]
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(message)


    # Tokenize and pad the input message
    sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(message)
    padded_sequence = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=10000, padding='post')
    
    #sample_message = ["Sample test message"]
    #tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sample_message)

    #sample_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sample_message)
    print(padded_sequence)
    #print("\n")
    #sample_padded_sequence = pad_sequences(sample_sequence, maxlen=10000,padding='post')
    ##print(sample_padded_sequence)
    

    # Make prediction 
    prediction = model.predict(padded_sequence)
    is_ai_message = prediction[0][0] > 0.4  # Assuming 0.4 as the threshold

    #response = {'is_ai_message': is_ai_message}
    if(is_ai_message):
        return jsonify({"status": "Message received", "printed_message": f"Is AI Written Message with Prediction{prediction[0][0]} for Email: {message}"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"status": "Message received", "printed_message": f"Is Human Written Message with Prediction{prediction[0][0]} for Email: {message}"})
    

```


Hi @ChibuikeS.Eze, welcome to the site. A typical problem with classification tasks is class imbalance. If your training data contains 99% AI-written emails and 1% human-written emails, probably your model will learn to simply predict AI-written regardless of the input. Can you provide information about the class ratio?

@noe The class ratio is 700 emails for AI-written emails and 700 for Human-written emails, with 1400 total, so a 50:50 ratio. Because my data set is even, I'm confused that there's such a drastic imbalance.

when running model.fit(), how does the plot of training and validation loss look like? Any sign of over-/under-fitting?
